# Kotlin scratch file output is missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio 3.2 and trying to run a scratch file, but can't find where println is output.

Contents of my scratch file:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

But the output window is missing "Hello, world!"

[image]

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `.kts` file doesn't require a `main` function. You can add the print statement at the top level.

This would explain the warning about `args` being unused, since `main` is never invoked.

> A script is a Kotlin source file (.kts) with top level executable code.
>   <sub>[Using the command line to run scripts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#using-the-command-line-to-run-scripts)</sub>

Comment: I should still get an output though, no?

I tried moving the print statement to the top level and it wasn't working either 

Comment: @starkej2 I don't think so, since nothing is actually executed (you just define a function)

Comment: ah...yeah you're right. Thanks for the help. I didn't notice the .kts file extension and also didn't notice my code was never executing that function. Sometimes another pair of eyes is all you need .

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the main function eg: main(args: Array){ } but leave the inside contents of main such as function calls in your scratches file eg: callingFun("PassingString"). 
Then hit the run button of the scratches file and then output should show up to the right side of the relevant lines of code.
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIMjz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep below lines

```
println("Hello, world!")
```

What Moira mentioned is correct because function main() is never called.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29804144)