# Unable to run Scratch file in Android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, scratch-file

I am trying to run Scratch files in Android studio 3.4.1 and unable to see the output. I have created two files one with .kts extension and other with .java extension.

Below mentioned is the .kts file

```
class Check {

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(args[0]+"Hello, World!")
}

}
```

As per this question [Kotlin scratch file output is missing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541636/kotlin-scratch-file-output-is-missing-in-android-studio) we can run this file by writing print statement at top-level but still error remains the same. Below mentioned is the error:

> "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java.exe"
>   "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio1\lib\idea_rt.jar=8940:C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android
>   Studio1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-compiler.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android
>   Studio1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android
>   Studio1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android
>   Studio1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-script-runtime.jar"
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler -kotlin-home "C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android Studio1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -script
>   C:/Users/ch-e01460.SPICEMONEY/.AndroidStudio3.4/config/scratches/scratch.kts

When i try to run this .Java file

```
class Scratch {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    println("Hello, World!");
}
}
```

I get the below mentioned error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Scratch Process finished with
>   exit code 1

I have checked many other solutions available here but none of them is working for me. Requesting everyone here to enlighten the path so that it can help others too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all the main class code - scratches are basically scripts.

A basic scratch.kts file can be created and run:

1. Right-click where you want to create the scratch file, e.g. `Scratches and Consoles -> scratches` and select `New -> scratch file`
2. Select "Kotlin"
3. Enter code, `println("Hello World!")`
4. Right-click on the file name and select `Run [scratch file].kts`

This will create a run config for you to use later.

[image: Run]

When you run the hello world example:
[image: Result]